# How to remove a class as each image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of images on a page. Each image has a CSS spinner that I want to show before each image is loaded. At the moment, I have it where when 'img' loads, the class 'spinner' is removed. This works but isn't what I want, as it removes the class 'spinner' whenever any 'img' is loaded.

Each img has it's own spinner and I want to only remove each 'individual' spinner class as each image loads.

Here is a basic jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/xvx6maty/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="work_items_wrapper">
    <a class="work_item_link" href="#">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
        <img class="workImage" src="http://i151.photobucket.com/albums/s129/Aiki_liann/cosmos.jpg">
    </a>

     <a class="work_item_link" href="#">
         <div class="spinner"></div>
         <img class="workImage" src="http://i151.photobucket.com/albums/s129/Aiki_liann/cosmos.jpg">
     </a>

      <a class="work_item_link_no_margin" href="#">
          <div class="spinner"></div>
          <img class="workImage" src="http://i151.photobucket.com/albums/s129/Aiki_liann/cosmos.jpg">
      </a>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.work_items_wrapper{
    margin: 2.8em auto;
}

.work_item_link{
    position: relative;
    width: 32%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;

    img{
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}

.work_item_link_no_margin{
    position: relative;
    width: 32%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    img{
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}

.spinner{
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    $("div").removeClass("spinner");
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

I replaced the first line of javascript with this to test again:

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
```

When I clicked only one of the images, all 3 spinner classes were removed.

How can I go about doing it so that when one image loads, that image's individual spinner is removed. Is it a case of looping through the images or something?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(this).siblings('div').removeClass("spinner");
```

This will remove the class for the div which is on the same level and has the same parent as the img in question.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/md8uqsfg/)

Comment: Thankyou..this works great as far as I can tell :). I've tested it with the click function and each spinner class is removed as each image is clicked.

Comment: In my demo (which i forked from yours) i use the click function.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `removeClass` line to this:

```
$(this).prev().removeClass("spinner");
```

This will get the current selection, `this`, which is the `img` which was loaded, and get it's previous sibling, which is the `div` you want.

Comment: Thankyou..this works great as far as I can tell :). I've tested it with the click function and each spinner class is removed as each image is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.prev()` to find previous `div`

Use

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).prev("div").removeClass("spinner");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1LezLwnL/)

Comment: Thankyou. I've tested it with the click function and each spinner class is removed as each image is clicked.